# Hi, I am a student and could give me a tip regarding these codes?

Tags: java

```
 System.out.print("Enter name:");
 name=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter nric: ");
 nric=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter age: ");
 age=sc.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Enter gender(male/female): ");
 gender=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter weight:");
 weight=sc.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Enter height: ");
 height=sc.nextDouble();
```

Well, every time after I enter age, I cannot enter gender. I would really appreciate it if you could help me, thanks.

Comment: this is duplicate please read marked question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because Scanner#nextInt method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine
 so for your program you have to put another nextLine for consuming the nextLine

it will perfect when adding the sc.nextLine after enter age

```
 System.out.print("Enter name:");
 name=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter nric: ");
 nric=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter age: ");
 age=sc.nextInt();
 sc.nextLine();// for consuming the nextLine

 System.out.print("Enter gender(male/female): ");
 gender=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter weight:");
 weight=sc.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Enter height: ");
 height=sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it

Comment: your most welcome give upvote for me

Answer (score 0):

nextInt() will stop after reading the int value, it wont go to new line to read values further.
you have to add a nextLine() after nextInt()
or
You can read age as String using nextLine() and later parse it as int using a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this before taking input of a line of a string.

```
sc= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Your code:

```
 System.out.print("Enter name:");
 name=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter nric: ");
 sc= new Scanner(System.in);
 nric=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter age: ");
 age=sc.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Enter gender(male/female): ");
 sc= new Scanner(System.in);
 gender=sc.nextLine();

 System.out.print("Enter weight:");
 weight=sc.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Enter height: ");
 height=sc.nextDouble();
```

When you invoke nextLine(), the line is removed from the buffer and effectively discarded from the Scanner.